# Unshifting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, ionic2

I have a Firebase service provider function returning a set of data by a promise object:

```
getPreviousChats(groupKey: string, offset: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // let previousChats: Array<any> = [];
    let previousChats: any[] = [];
    const chatRef = this.chatsRef.child(groupKey).orderByKey().endAt(offset).limitToLast(5);
    chatRef.once('value', snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        previousChats.push({
          id: childSnapshot.key,
          message: childSnapshot.val().message,
          createTime: childSnapshot.val().createTime
        });
        return false; // forEach returns boolean
      });
    });
    resolve(previousChats);
  });
}
```

Meanwhile, an Ionic page function calls `getPreviousChats()` to retrieve previous chat data and add it to current page layout by `unshift()`:

```
loadPreviousChats(refresher) {
  this.dataService.getPreviousChats(this.groupKey, this.chats[0].id).then(data => {
    this.chats.unshift(data);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('loadPreviousChats error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Async operation has ended');
    refresher.complete();
  }, 1000); 
}
```

Unfortunately, somehow `this.chats.unshift(data);` inserts the `data` in front of current `this.chats` array with an extra layer of array:

```
this.chats:  Array[6]
              0: Array[5]
                0: Object
                1: Object
                2: Object
                3: Object
                4: Object
                 length: 5
                 __proto__: Array[0]
              1: Object
              2: Object
              3: Object
              4: Object
              5: Object
               length: 6
               __proto__: Array[0]
```

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: consider using push() instead of unshift()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what am I missing here?

That that's what `unshift` does: It takes the value you give it and inserts it at the beginning of the array. The value you're giving it is an array reference, so that's what it puts in the array.

If you want to *append* those entries to `this.chats`, you can do that with `push`; it's a bit awkward in ES5 and earlier:

```
this.chats.push.apply(this.chats, data);
```

a bit clearer in ES2015+ with spread syntax:

```
this.chats.push(...data);
```

---

Side note: You're also falling prey to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call): You're resolving your promise in `getPreviousChats` too soon, before the `once` callback is called (I'm assuming it's an asynchronous operation, otherwise it seems odd for it to use a callback like that). Move the `resolve` call *into* the callback.

Comment: Cool! The problem was really about "resolve". After moving it to callback, everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can insert the new Array Items into the existing one like so:

```
let chats = [...newChats, ...oldChats]; //or oldChats first
```

or, you can use concat like so:

```
let chats = oldChats.concat(newChats);
```

I would prefer method one, since it creates a swallow copy of each array, without modifying the originals.